# detached entity passed to persist: Not allowing me to save the object

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

```
public class Certification implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 6045812180225694344L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@Column(name = "certification_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private String id;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="certification", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<CertificationPrerequisite> prerequisites;

}

public class CertificationPrerequisite implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6045812180225694344L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")   
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
private String id;

@ManyToOne(optional = false, targetEntity = Certification.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="certification_id", referencedColumnName = "certification_id")
private Certification certification;

@Column(name = "prerequisite_certification_id")
private String prerequisiteCertificationId;

}
```

When I save this certification object including CertificationPrerequisite, certification object inside Id coming as null, which I suspect not allowing to save the object. Is there any way to do this better?

```
public interface CertificationRepository extends JpaRepository<Certification, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Certification> {

}

Certification certification  =  new Certification();
CertificationPrerequisite certificationPrerequisite = new 
CertificationPrerequisite();
certificationPrerequisite.setCertification(certification);
certification.setCertificationPrerequisite(certificationPrerequisite);
CertificationRepository.save(certification);
```

Comment: Certification Serializable - you see what's missing there?

Comment: you mean implements? I missed it during edit

Comment: Yeah, that's missing. However, where is the code which actually stores the object? Where is the stacktrace of the error and so on? Just the models aren't enough to find out why it's detached.